# Trouble with Custom UIAlertView in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

[image]

I am trying to lay buttons on top of a background image for a UIAlertView in Cocos2d. Its not working with the code below. any suggestions?

```
UIAlertView *Win=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Win" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Next" otherButtonTitles:@"Replay",@"Quit", nil];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50, -30, 400, 300)];

    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levelcleared.png"]];
    UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 70, 70)];

    NSString *path2= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"alertviewhome.png"]];
    UIImage *bkgImg2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path2];

    imageView2.
    [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
    [imageView2 setImage:bkgImg2];

    [bkgImg release];
    [path release];

    [Win addSubview:imageView];
    [Win addSubview:imageView2];


    [imageView release];


    [Win show];
    [Win release];
```

Comment: ssorry dude pressed submit too quick.

Comment: so question is at top.  It will not let me add the buttons to the background image for the Custom UIAlertView.

Comment: I'd like to add the images as a picture to explain this more so if you do not have any suggestions on what might do the trick please vote up.

Comment: what's up with that orphan `imageView2.` in the middle of the code block?  does this thing actually compile?

Comment: @Katelyn "It's not working .. any suggestions?" is not a real question. For future reference: describe what exactly isn't working and what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own alert-like view (which can be added as a subview to whatever view you want to display it over) and don't use UIAlertView for what you're trying to do.

The [Apple documentation for UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) says:

> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

To me, that means that if you try to add subviews (like those buttons or images or whatever), you're likely to have screwy/unexpected/gross results.

Comment: yup thats what i just finished reading :(  so sad. when using cocos i dont think ill be able to write my own alert view code.

Comment: But what Michael is saying is the same thing. You can create a custom subview with your graphics, with buttons that do the exact same thing as the buttons in an UIAlertView. The easiest option would be put that wooden plank in the background, with the three options as individual custom buttons that link to an action.

Comment: @master_gracey sorry this is my first cocos2d project so i may sound like an idiot. but i was pretty sure i could not create custom subviews for it only scenes.

Comment: I think I see what you are talking about though I could have a "mock scene"with the background and three buttons as menu items connected to their actions. okay, im going to try that now.

Comment: @KatelynGleason, no apology necessary. You have to start somewhere and by working at it you're on the right track! In your case, the easiest way to go is lay out the UIImageView and each custom button in Interface Builder. Link each button with an IBAction that does their intended purpose. Each action can handle dismissing the subview and bringing the new appropriate view into position.